# error connection to amazon aws with laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

i establish connection to amazon aws like this

```
    $s3 =  AwsFacade::createClient('s3');
    $s3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => 'NameBuckut',
            'secret'    => 'SecretKey',
            'Key'    => 'Key',
            'SourceFile' => 'pathImage/Image.png',
        ));
```

i have this error :

```
exception &#039;Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception&#039; with message &#039;Error executing &quot;GetObject&quot; on &quot;https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/Key&quot;; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/key` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;Error&gt;&lt;Code&gt;AuthorizationHeaderMalformed&lt;/Code&gt;&lt;Message&gt;The authorization header (truncated...)
```

how can i resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have enough permissions to fetch the object.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

You can see here some meanings and when you search for your return "AuthorizationHeaderMalformed" you get the following meaning

```
The authorization header you provided is invalid.
```

So you should check if your permissions are correct and you have enough rights to get the file. Check the "Bucket policy", too.

Laravel has support for S3 so you can configure it and use it over the Storage perhaps that is working better.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Comment: it is related to the server from where we connect. 
we connected from the same server with NodeJs and we haven't error of permession.

Comment: It's difficult to say so do you have some Webfilter or something else that break your request? Is the Server in the AWS infrastructure or outside? Do you have defined IPs or something else in your bucket policy? That it's working another place?

Comment: i am in the same server from where we executed with NodeJs and it works. But with laravel it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you should check your configuration and credentials. Try to use the internal solution from Laravel and access it over the storage perhaps that is working.